# Print formatted string with variables

Tags: string, console, scheme

Im going through a book in Scheme that has me using the writeln function. It expects me to be able to give it a series of strings and variables that it will then output to the console like so.
`(writeln "the number is " 4 "!")` with the expected output being `the number is 4!`.

However when running and looking up documentation writeln and similar functions like display only take two arguments the data and an output. Giveing writeln multipule arguments like `"the number is "`, `4` and `"!"` will cause an error.

How does one print the formatted string like the book is expecting?

I have tried...
Quoting the expression giving to writeln.
trying alternative functions like display.

Comment: Which Scheme version is your book using? I/O is very version-specific. (And Racket is not Scheme.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The printf function solves this

Comment: There is not `printf` procdure descrbed in the language specification. That is any of the RnRS documents. You are answering for a DIFFERENT language.